# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Print() displays print dialog

Tags: .net, winforms, printing, webbrowser-control

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print.aspx):

> This method prints the current
>   document without requiring further
>   user input. To display the Print
>   dialog box prior to printing, use the 
>   ShowPrintDialog method.

But when I execute .Print() in my code, I always get the normal Windows printer dialog box.

My question is simply: how do I avoid display of the printer dialog?

As an alternative, is there a better/easier way to print both HTML and PDF from within a Windows Forms application? WebBrowser does everything I need except for this problem.

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you requesting the right security permissions?

> SecurityPermission  for immediate
>   callers to use this control. Demand
>   value: LinkDemand; Named Permission
>   Sets: FullTrust.
>
> PrintingPermission  to access the
>   printer through this method. Demand
>   value: Demand. Associated enumeration:
>   DefaultPrinting.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to do the same thing even when I request and obtain all permissions.

Comment: I never solved the immediate problem, but thanks to other Q&A on Stack Overflow I discovered iTextSharp. That helped me build one big PDF containing the entire print batch. Getting the print dialog once at the beginning of the batch is fine!

Thank you for your response.